# nginx reverse-proxy docker applications

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to set up nginx as proxy with the following functionality:
If www.mydomain.com is called, hand out static content.
If www.mydomain.com/wekan is called, redirect to my Wekan-Dokan container.
For keeping it simple, everything is on localhost and no network required.

This is my nginx configuration:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        server{
                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:9050;
                }
                location /wekan {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
                }
                location /pics {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost/example.jpg;
                }
                location ~ \.(gif|jpg|png)$ {
                        root /home/myUser/serverTest/data/images;
                }
        }
        server{
                listen 9050;
                root /home/myUser/serverTest/data/up1;
                location / {
                }
        }
```

}

And here is my docker-compose for the Wekan App:

```
version: '2'    

services:

  wekandb:
    image: mongo:3.2.21
    container_name: wekan-db
    restart: always
    command: mongod --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
    networks:
      - wekan-tier
    expose:
      - 27017
    volumes:
      - /home/myUser/wekan/wekan-db:/data/db
      - /home/myUser/wekan/wekan-db-dump:/dump

  wekan:
    image: quay.io/wekan/wekan
    container_name: wekan-app
    restart: always
    networks:
      - wekan-tier
    ports:
      # Docker outsideport:insideport
      - 3001:8080
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://wekandb:27017/wekan
      - ROOT_URL=http://localhost
```

So as my basic understanding of nginx,
calling `localhost:3001` and calling `localhost/wekan` should be the same, since `localhost/wekan` gets redirected to `localhost:3001`.
This is not the case (it gets redirected to a wekan "page not found" version)

Comment: Try with an ending slash? `location /wekan/ `

Comment: also your nginx is listening on 9050, so localhost:9050/wekan and localhost:3001 should be the same

Comment: that doesnt work either